# Give all links to a certain domain the "no follow"-attribute automatically? (html, css)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink, nofollow

I just want to give all external links which go to a certain domain (and all of its subpages) the "no follow"-attribute automatically. Only to a certain domain, not all external links. I use Wordpress, so maybe there is a plugin (I didnt find any)?

Is that possible with css or html without doing it 1000 times via hand manually?

Thanks a bunch!

PS: sry for my bad english, I am no native speaker :(

Comment: I'd be surprised if this isn't possible within Wordpress itself (though for specific Wordpress advice you may find that [wordpress.se] is more knowledgeable on such things), otherwise it's not possible with pure CSS or HTML; you'd need to use JavaScript (with, or without, one of its many libraries), but doing this client-side feels wasteful of client resources.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with CSS or HTML. But there are a lot of plugins doing that job. By default, all outgoing links get a nofollow. But you can configure most plugins to exclude certain domains. Unfortunately, you have to go the other way around, exclude your "certain domain".

Try [External Links](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sem-external-links/) or [Ultimate Nofollow](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nofollow/) as a start. It's not too complicated.

But there are lots of [others](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=nofollow).

OR write a custom function in your functions.php. Take [this tutorial](https://digitizor.com/add-nofollow-external-wordpress/) as an example and modify the processing - so that it only processes your custom domain.

Comment: Thank you firstly! Unfortunately none of this have in my understanding the option to include only one certain domain and all its subpages for nofollow (and I am a coding noob without doing it with php). Only to exclude some domain from nofollow is possible. Or at ultimate nofollow you have only "A nofollow option for individual blogroll links". Moreover all these plugins are not up to date and so I fear that they are not working anymore sometimes.